# Using cd command with slash?

Tags: linux

I was reading about `CD command` in linux , and i have this problem

```
[**@server2 ~]$ ls
access-logs  etc  logs  mail  perl5  public_ftp  public_html  ssl  tmp  www
```

when i want to move to `www` dir i use this :

```
[**@server2 ~]$ cd www
[**@server2 www]$
```

but why when i use `/` before dir name , its give me an error :

```
[**@server2 ~]$ cd /www
-bash: cd: /www: No such file or directory
```

even i try another dir and working when i add `/` :

```
[**@server2 ~]$ cd /etc/
[**@server2 etc]$
```

> note:/etc/ is in another folder .

i also check this https://www.tecmint.com/cd-command-in-linux/ but it didn't help me.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/117435/htg-explains-the-linux-directory-structure-explained/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` in Linux is s `Root directory` for the system, so if you typed: `cd /www` `www` has to be located under `/` directory to access it.